# Error launching vschrome_diag when Visual Studio 2017 starts debug on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

From today, when I start debug of a web application on Chrome this error appear.
[image]

Then I click on OK and this other error appear
[image]

In the last day, I've update neither Visual Studio or Chrome.

Comment: Are you using different login to run VS2017?

Comment: @ravish.hacker no, I'm using the same login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was enough to uninstall Chrome, restart the PC and then reinstall Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\vschrome_diag file worked for me.