# Invalid pointer | This file does not have an app associated with it

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have an **ASP.NET Core** application which was running fine but while developing (and after the **Windows 10 April update, most likely just a coincidence**) suddenly, I got two messages:

> 1. This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed,
>      create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.
> 2. Unable to start program 'programName' Invalid pointer

Result: I cannot debug/ run my application anymore. (Start Debugging/ Start Without Debugging)

I found some scary search results talking about a corrupt file system but I don't think that it is something like that in my case...

I checked my startup projects, restarted Visual Studio, restarted the whole system... nothing helped.

**Update:** After installing the latest Visual Studio update (15.7.1), the message I get when I activate the JavaScript debugging again has changed. Now it states:

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 123.0.0.0.1:53232)

Result: Still the same. Only the error message changed.

Any hints, ideas about that one? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If not an answer at least a workaround. I can work again if I tweak the debug options

> Debug -> Options -> General -> Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET
>   (Chrome and IE)

If I **disable** this feature, I can debug and run my application again. But I still don't understand why this is happening now nor how to use JavaScript debugging now...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2017. It was caused by my antivirus (bitdefender) blocking a chrome temp file. I set it to ignore that file and that fixed my debug issues.

The file was C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\vschrome_diag.lnk

According to this, re-installing chrome may fix the problem.
[Error launching vschrome_diag when Visual Studio 2017 starts debug on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154397/error-launching-vschrome-diag-when-visual-studio-2017-starts-debug-on-chrome)